# PHP function inside while returns invalid values if execute for more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

If I execute the below script for than one row using where clause it will return invalid or wrong values and if I execute it only for row value it is giving correct result..

```
<?php
include "database.php";

function getTotalLegL($memid,$leg)
{
$sql="select * from register where sid='".$memid."' and position='".$leg."'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
global $totala;
global $totalL;
$totala=$totala+mysql_num_rows($res);
            if($row['regid']!='')
            {
              if($row['pack']=='Free'){
                  $tot=0;
              }
              if($row['pack']=='Silver'){
                  $tot=1;
              }
              if($row['pack']=='Gold'){
                  $tot=2;
              }
                getTotalLegL($row['regid'],'Var1');
                getTotalLegL($row['regid'],'Var2');
                $totalL+=$tot;
          }
return $totalL;
}
function getTotalLegR($memid,$leg)
{
$sql="select * from register where sid='".$memid."' and position='".$leg."'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
global $totalR;
            if($row['regid']!='')
            {
              if($row['pack']=='Free'){
                  $tot=0;
              }
              if($row['pack']=='Silver'){
                  $tot=1;
              }
              if($row['pack']=='Gold'){
                  $tot=2;
              }
                getTotalLegR($row['regid'],'Var1');
                getTotalLegR($row['regid'],'Var2');
                $totalR+=$tot;
          }
return $totalR;
}

  $sno=1;
$res=mysql_query("select * from register");
echo '<table>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $mid=$row['regid'];
    $lbv=getTotalLegL($mid,'Var1');
    $rbv=getTotalLegR($mid,'Var2');
echo '<tr><td>'.$sno.'<td>'.$mid.'<td>'.$lbv.'<td>'.$rbv.'</td></tr>';
unset($lbv,$rbv);
$sno++;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I don't the reason why it is giving correct values for one where clause value not for the multiple values...

getTotalLegL(),getTotalLegR() are function which will collect total downline information of $mid.

So If i go with where clause with only value & query is $res=mysql_query("select * from register limit 0,1"); I'll get correct values...
but if i run it liek $res=mysql_query("select * from register limit 0,10");
I am not getting correct values,,

So kindly please help me anyone and save my day...

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't be using `global` in here, if you need values to be passed around, add them as parameters to your function.

Comment: Do not use select *, name your columns

Comment: 1. I don't understand the purpose of recursive function calls here. What exactly you are trying to do here? 2. You're already inside php, so remove `<?php` above `$sno=1;` 3. Syntax error here, `$res=mysql_query("select * from register);`, missing closing `"`. 4. You said you're doing `$res=mysql_query("select * from register limit 0,1);` but where is that in the code?

Comment: You should get into the habit of accepting answers, it not only closes the question but also encourages other developers to help you further. Currently it seems all your questions are *open*. See [how to accept answers on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Rajdeep,As you said,I am soory to accept the answers,I don't repeat this in future..Thanks for the concern,,

Comment: Rajdeep,I updated the code as per request by suntax mistakes..Kindly again look into this..The main objective in this one is just getting the values of each var1,var2 using getTotalLegL(),getTotalLegR() functions when excute the mysql while loop..1st case I passed only one parameter query like this "select * from register limit 0,1" here I get the accurate result,But when I run query "select * from register limit 0,10" for getting records..It is not giving correct values..